# host simple python app which gets stockdata on VM to run automatically

Tags: python-3.x, heroku, virtual-machine, google-compute-engine

```
from nsepy import get_history
from datetime import date, timedelta

end_day = date.today()
start_day = end_day - timedelta(365)
def nse_stock(self):
        df = get_history(symbol='TCS', start=start_day, end=end_day)

        print(df)
self()
```

i want to host this code on a VM or cloud so that it can run at a specified time daily.
i've tried running this code on GCP looking at various videos and editing out some stuff. But it fails getting data.

Comment: Can you show any of the process or describe what you’ve tried when deploying this code?

Comment: Please provide more details about your steps and issues. Also, please check documentation https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

Comment: i've started a server on gcp (ubuntu 18.04) with firewall settings to allow all http and https requests.

i've pip installed nsepy and copied the code using nano.
when i try to run it.
python3 filename.py
nothing happens next.
its like a wait forever situation

Comment: Hi sir i am also facing this same issue . Have u figured out any solution to this yet ?? If yes then do share